# Ejecutar una funcion JavaScript principiantes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

hola tengo el siguiente codigo muy sencillo.
objetivo :  apretar el button estando el input vacio tiene que imprimir el alert jquery.
como pueden ver
[[image: código html]]

el codigo script js :

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
 
 function validar() {

    var n_usuario =document.getElementById("usuario").value;


         if (n_usuario = "") {

          $("#usuario").alter("por favor rellena este campo");
         }


 }
    
 });
```

Comment: Si, lo veo, genial

Comment: Entonces... ¿cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: No debería ser `alert`? lo digo por que parece que simplemente lo escribiste mal

Comment: Por otro lado para el escenario que expones y dado el código que llevas te diría que ni siquiera hace sentido que ocupes a JQuery

Comment: Además tienes mal escrita la comprobación en el condicional, para asignar se usa un `=` y para una comparación estricta van `===` que en todo caso es lo que tendrías que implementar

Comment: última observación, ¿por qué generas la variable `n_usuario` dentro de la función? esta debería ser declarada una sola vez y recibir su valor y posterior la usas en la función

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estas utilizando `jQuery` no es necesario que sigas usando instrucciones de `Javascript`. Remueve de tu botón el `onclick="validar()"`, y crea mejor el `evento click` con `jQuery` por medio de su `id`.

De igual manera, en lugar de usar el `document.getElementById("usuario").value;`, usa la función `$('#usuario').val();`, que hace exactamente lo mismo, pero si te das cuenta con menos código.

Y en tu `if` no estás haciendo comparación, solo hay un `=` cuando deberían ser dos `==`, de lo contrario nunca va a entrar.

Y por úlimo, la función `alter()` que usas aquí **=>** `$("#usuario").alter("por favor rellena este campo");` no existe en `jQuery`, por lo cual marcará ese `error`. Me imagino que quieres usar la instrucción `alert`.

Este sería el código correcto, pruébalo:

```
$("#button").click(function(){

   var n_usuario = $('#usuario').val();

   if(n_usuario == ""){

     alert("por favor rellena este campo");
   }
});
```

Comment: Solo 2 puntos a aclarar: 1. Decirle al OP con cual deberia usarse, si con 2 `==` o 3 `===`, lo ultimo es declaracion estricta. 2. El metodo `alert` no es propio de `jQuery` sino de `JS`

Comment: @JuanRivera Independientemente de si usa `==` o `===`, solo se le indicó que solo uso `=`, por lo cual nunca iba a entrar en funcionamiento ese `if`.... Y sí, lo sé, así como el `alert` no es propio de `jQuery`, hay más instrucciones que no lo son pero que de igual manera se llegan a utilizar en algún punto del desarrollo, le hice la observación ya que estaba utilizando instrucciones de `Javascript` mezclado con `jQuery`, cuando bien podría escribir todas las instrucciones con `jQuery`.

Comment: Solo dije para "aclarar" ya que del primer punto le dices "*deberían ser dos*", del punto 2 de igual forma, le dices "*no existe en jQuery*"

Comment: @valle50 . gracias por tu respuesta resolvi el incomveniente , lo que me llama la atencio es que ningun momento Vs Code me aviso de un posible error de sintaxis , he notado varias veces que por errores minimos no  ejecuta correctamente .saludos